# Escape character to escape "." when Editing an XML file with powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

```
                      <Something>
                          <Somethings.few>
                            <thing  stuff1="XX"  stuff2= "XXX">
                               <thing2>
                                 <stuff value="YY">
                                </thing2>
                            </thing>
                          </Somethings.few>
                      </Something>
```

I want to change the value of stuff1 using powershell, but the problem is with Somethings.few

```
$xmlFile = [xml](gc file.xml)
$xmlFile.Something.Somethings.few.thing.stuff1="ZZ"
```

does not work for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try like this:

```
 $xmlfile.Something.'Somethings.few'.thing.stuff1 = "zz"
```

No needs to escape the dot just enclose in `'` any name composed with it.